# Cloning Machines joined to Domain using SSSD

Tags: debian, images, domain, cloning, sssd

We are using Amazon Web services and have a number of Debian boxes that are registered to our domain. I want to clone these boxes, change there hostname and rejoin them to the domain without impacting the existing machines.

So if I have Webserver-A.domain.local

I want to clone it so i have

Webserver-B.domain.local and Webserver-C.domain.local

With all three AD joined.

Can suggest the best steps to take with a Linux based machine to insure that we don't get conflict during the cloning process.

Thank you

Aaron